# Get value of variable index in particular dimension

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Say if i have a tensor that is

```
value = torch.tensor([

    [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]],
    [[2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]],
])
```

essentially with shape `(2,2,3)`.

Now say if i have an `index = [1, 0]`, which means I want to take:

```
# row 1 of [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]], giving me: [1, 1, 1]
# row 0 of [[2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], giving me: [2, 2, 2]
```

So that the final output:

```
output = torch.tensor([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]])
```

is there a vectorized way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use advanced indexing.
I can't find a good pytorch document about this, but I believe it works as same as numpy, so here's the numpy's [document about indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

```
import torch

value = torch.tensor([

    [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]],
    [[2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]],
])

index = [1, 0]
i = range(0,2)

result = value[i, index]
# same as result = value[i, index, :] 

print(result)
```